# Recognise blank spaces inside an input file Fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm trying to develop a program in Fortran and I need it to recognize blank spaces inside the input file in order to jump to the next line if there is one for one particular value.

For example if the input is:

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
5.0     6.0 7.0
8.0 9.0 1.0 2.0
3.0 0.0 4.0 5.0
```

The program should write just the first, the third and the last line. Is it possible?

Comment: You show us a file you call an *input* file, then ask about writing lines.  Can you clarify your question ?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest to take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question is very unclear. What exactly should happen when the program encounters the line with the missing number? Do you have any code, that you want to modify, already? If yes, you should show it.

Comment: Are you actually looking to find blank spaces, or to print only the lines that contain four numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file line by line and then look for spaces in the line:

```
program StackOverflowSandbox

implicit none

CHARACTER (LEN=15)             :: NextLine
LOGICAL                         :: OneFound
LOGICAL                         :: TwoFound
integer                         :: i
integer                         :: j

open(2, FILE = 'Input.txt')

SpaceFinder: DO i = 1, 4

    Read(2,'(A)') NextLine
    DO j = 1,15    
        if(NextLine(j:j).EQ.' ') then
              if(OneFound) then
                TwoFound = .TRUE.
                EXIT SpaceFinder
              else
                OneFound = .TRUE.
              end if
        else
            OneFound = .FALSE.
        end if        
    END DO               
END DO SpaceFinder

if(TwoFound) then
    Write(*,*) 'Found It!'    
end if

end program StackOverflowSandbox
```

Comment: I think it would be a bit cleaner to use the `INDEX` function to search for the 2 spaces rather than all that looping over `j`. `twofound=INDEX(nextline,'  ')>0` should do it.

Comment: makes sense. My main point is that the strategy is to read one line and then process it. There are a few things that will need to be changed such as the length of the string to hold the line and such.